# Will DART fire its ion engine to accelerate prior to impact?

Tags: acceleration, kerbal-space-program, asteroid-redirect-mission, dart

I'm an avid KSP player. Like some of them, I've been playing the DART simulation on the game. I've typically achieved impact velocities of 5-7 km/s, the higher end being achieved by propulsive acceleration close to impact. Will DART do this in real life (accelerating close to impact)?

Comment: There is also the question: do we need a higher speed impact? This is a "downsized" exercise to get the data for the "big one" threat, if ever. So, perhaps the objective is to have just enough velocity to incur a measurable deviation, not really a "show of might".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It almost does not matter, with a maximum acceleration of $0.6mm/s^2$ (1/16500th of a g),
the probe could only change its velocity by 1m/s over the last ten thousand kilometers of approach.

But no, they would not be thrusting during final approach, so as to simplify confirmation of accuracy and pointing restrictions on the probe.
Accuracy of impact is *everything* in this game.

(the KSP ion thruster is between 10 000 and 100 000 times too strong, compared to real life, and not a good comparison)

Comment: Yeah the ION engine does nothing here; but somehow it was supposed to be able to do course corrections on final approach by something. I suppose it could burn whatever that is.